# How do I add values, that are assigned when certain characters meet certain criteria, in Python?

Tags: python

I have to add and subtract values when letters and numbers are in certain places in the random string of characters as follows:

*1. Letters within a string = +1*

*2. Capital letter beginning string = +1*

*3. Capital letter within or at end of string = -2*

*4. Number or other symbol in string = -2 AND deduct .25 for each letter in
string.*

I can get the random string of characters, but I am having difficulty adding these values with 'x'.

```
import random
import math

x=0

def randstr(localX):
    a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    b = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    c = '0123456789'
    d = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
    rs = (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d))
    print rs
    if rs[0] in b:
        localX += 1
    if rs[0] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[1] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[2] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[3] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[4] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[5] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[6] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[7] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[8] in a:
        localX += 1
    elif rs[9] in a:
        localX += 1
    if rs[1] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[2] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[3] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[4] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[5] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[6] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[7] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[8] in b:
        localX -= 2
    elif rs[9] in b:
        localX -= 2
    if rs[0] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[1] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[2] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[3] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[4] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[5] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[6] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[7] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[8] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [9] in a:
            localX -= .25
    elif rs[9] in c:
        localX -= 2
        if rs [0] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [1] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [2] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [3] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [4] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [5] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [6] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [7] in a:
            localX -= .25
        elif rs [8] in a:
            localX -= .25
    return rs
    return localX
randstr(localX)
```

Comment: A `for` loop may come in handy here...

Comment: Use some loops. I suggest reading the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: As a side note: `a = ('…')` does the exact same thing as `a = '…'`; adding extra parentheses like that just confuses the reader. (Plus, you can write all of those a lot more simply as `a = string.ascii_lowercase`, `b = string.ascii_uppercase`, etc. Or, better, just _use_ those nice, meaningful names that come with the language instead of calling them `a` and `b` and so forth. Or, even better, use methods in the `str` objects, like `s.isupper()`, etc., instead.)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the parentheses note. I am used to another class using them constantly (Scheme Programming: CSCI-C211).

Comment: @TravisJ.Land: Scheme uses them for function calls, though. You wouldn't arbitrarily stick additional parentheses into a Scheme program; why do so here?

Comment: on a side note if you are doing some kind of learning algorithm you will probably be better off implementing letter frequency stuff ... this(the method you are planning on using) will just result in capitalized giberish

Comment: Very right. I'm very beginner though so I kind of carried the parentheses rules over. I now know not to do so again.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/5QNuDbyD) is quick pythonic implementation that incorporates all of the hints given above (plus another two—using `enumerate` to distinguish the first position from later positions, and keeping count of the number of letters so you don't need to keep re-counting them for each non-letter). It would be more helpful if someone showed you each improvement step by step, but I don't have infinite time; hopefully that's enough for you to figure things out.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'd go through chapters [3](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) and [4](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) of the official Python tutorial (or the equivalent parts of some third-party tutorial). It shouldn't take long to get through it, and it will explain nearly everything people are suggesting here—`for` loops, local variables and returning values from functions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the value of x to be affected at global scope by your function, your x would have had to have been initialized at global scope.

Right now, it's being initialized at local scope within your function. Either return the value of your x, or initialize it at global scope (.. outside of any function) before calling your function., ie:

Option 0:

```
#declare x at global scope
x = 0
#declare the function affecting x anywhere you want
def randstr():
    global x
    #..... code affecting the value of x
    return whatever
#then use your function affecting x
randstr()
```

Option 1: (better)

```
#pass x as argument 
def randstr(x):
    #..... code affecting the value of x
    return x
x = 0
#other code affecting x
#.....
#pass x as argument and modify the value of your local x
x = randstr(x)
```

Obviously, I think there are other issues with your code, as the complete lack of loops which really needs to be addressed, but I'm infering here that you are a student, learning.

```
for characterVar in stringVar:
        #code that is repeated for each character
        #handling the character by manipulatin characterVar
        if characterVar == "a" :
            #do stuff if a character in stringVar is a "a"
```

is the way you should loop through your string

example of something that could work. Please note that the code should instead use regex, and that the way the string is generated is just bad, but that this was conserved from the original answer to not complicate things too much for OP

```
import random
import math

def randStr():
    x = 0.0
    small = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    capitals = ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    digits = ('0123456789')
    d = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
    rs = (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d)) + (random.choice(d))
    qtyOfLetters = 0
    for char in rs:
        if char in small or char in capitals:
            qtyOfLetters += 1
    x += qtyOfLetters
    if rs[0] in capitals:
        x += 1.0
    for c in rs:
        if c in capitals:
            x -= 2.0
        if not ((c in capitals) or (c in small)):
            x -= (2.0 + 0.25 * qtyOfLetters)
    return (rs,x)

result = randStr()
print ("Generated string : '" + str(result[0]) +"'")
print ("result : " + str(result[1]))
```

Comment: Indeed, I agree loops would be very useful if I knew how to use them (which I plan to learn soon), but that isn't the important part at the moment as you stated. I just need to come up with a working program for the moment. On the other hand, what is the difference between global and local? How do I implement each?

Comment: locals are defined within the functions (in python, within an indentation block, which is the textual way python represents scope, like curly braces in C/C++/C#/Java), while globals are defined outside of any functions, ... so without indentation, in Python.

Comment: Option 0 would also require a `global x` statement; otherwise, the first `x += 1` or the like to get executed will raise an `UnboundLocalError`. But since, as you make very clear, option 1 is a lot better anyway, this isn't a big deal.

Comment: you are right, thanks for this, looks like javascript has messed with my understanding of bad python

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me say that it's great that you're learning to write software and I think Python is the perfect language for beginners. It also sounds like you're teaching yourself, and getting your hands dirty by jumping in is a great way to learn.

However, you need to reflect on how your time is best spent while learning. When you're starting out, often the biggest problem is not knowing "what is the right question to ask?" How do you know to read a tutorial on `for` loops if you've never heard of `for` loops in the first place?

There are two solutions to this:

1) Start with some guided tutorials so that you quickly come up to speed on the most common language features. You will really save yourself a lot of time if you come to grips with the basics.

2) Learn to recognize when there "should be a better way" of doing something. If you're having to go to a lot of effort in implementing a task, there is often a better way to go about it. For example when you had to type out the same code over and over (or copy-paste chunks of code, changing bits here and there), you could have tried searching for "how can I reduce copy pasting in code" or "how can I reduce code duplication". This is just an example of course, but learning when to consult the documentation is a very important skill for a programmer.

Once you feel you've gained a bit of knowledge, your programs will quickly improve. Here are some tips for improving your existing code:

There are some predefined strings in the `string` module that will improve readability of your code

```
>>> import string
>>> string.lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

Here's an example of a simple `for` loop

```
>>> my_string = "hello"
>>> for my_char in my_string:
...     print my_char
... 
h
e
l
l
o
```

And another that includes the index of each character:

```
>>> for my_index, my_char in enumerate(my_string):
...     print my_index, my_char
... 
0 h
1 e
2 l
3 l
4 o
```

There's a good quote that applies here:

> “Work smarter, not harder”
>
> -- Carl Barks

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't work hard of course, but be smart about knowing when you can save yourself time.

Comment: That's exactly my problem: What do I ask? Thank you for your wonderful insight :)